# How to get authentication information of the user that triggered firebase cloud function 'onUpdate' or 'onWrite'?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I use a cloud background triggered firebase function 'onUpdate' to respond to any event where there is an update on a collection "trns". As clearly documented in [Cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=1st) documentation, the callback takes on two parameters, 'change' and 'context'.

Firebase documentation is clear on the [context](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.eventcontext.md#eventcontext_interface) , one of the properties of the 'EventContext interface' (context) is 'auth'. It is suppose to provide what I/m looking for, namely authentication information for the user that triggered the function. From 'auth', I'm specifically looking for 'displayName'.

But then, when you zoom deep into 'EventContext.auth' you realise that it says 'This field is only populated for Realtime Database triggers and Callable functions' and I'm using neither.

Is there a work around where I can still use either 'onUpdate' or 'onWrite' and still have access to 'auth' property?

```
    exports.updateTrn = functions.firestore.document("trns/{trnsId}")
    .onUpdate( (change, context) => {
        console.log(`context`, context)
    }
```

Comment: As you've found, no information about the user triggers a Cloud Function through Firestore is passed along automatically. The common approach is to pass the user yourself either in the path to the document, or as data in the document itself, and then use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, if I can ask, why is this feature available only in 'Realtime Database triggers and Callable function'? Is there a specific reason why its not available on background trigger functions?